# "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when retriveing PFFile from Parse.com

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8, xcode6

i've a problem when i retrieve a PFFile stored in Parse.com

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()
let userImageFile = user["profileImage"] as PFFile
            userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if imageData != nil{
                        let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                        self.profileImage.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
```

The error start at **line two**.
Column "profileImage" exists, but it can be empty.

Someone can help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if let userImageFile = user["profileImage"] as? PFFile {

}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you.
Resolve:

if let userImageFile = user[ParseUserClassTablesName.PROFILEIMAGE.description()] as? PFFile{
                userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        if imageData != nil{
                            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                            self.profileImage.image = image
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: How did that solve the issue for you? I got the same problem and this does not solve the problem