# My Code quit working after a week - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8

This bit of code has been working for me ever since I wrote it, yet today it decided to quit working on me. I've been trying to resolve the issue the majority of the day, and it's slowly driving me crazy. I keep getting a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error. I understand what it means, but I can't seem to fix it. I found this thread - ["unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when retriveing PFFile from Parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948401/unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-when-retriveing-pffi) - and tried the solution, but it did not work. Here is my code:

```
if let userImageFile: AnyObject = content["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
println("Here is your userImageFile: \(userImageFile)")
            userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil
                {
                    var contentImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    self.feedView.image = contentImage
                }
            }
        }
```

I know that the userImageFile is not nil, because the print line I have put in before getDataInBackgroundWithBlock correctly prints out the PFFile i'm trying to access from my Parse data browser. I just don't understand how it can work for a week and then suddenly stop working. If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

**ANSWER**

So after banging my head into my desk for many hours, I finally said screw it and deleted my code, only to re-write it and have it work again...This is now working code, but I've also updated it a bit with the suggestions of the post below.

```
if let imageFile: AnyObject = content["imageFile"] as? PFFile {

            imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

                if let imageData = imageData
                {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                    {
                        var contentImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
                        self.feedView.image = contentImage
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Do something else
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if `userImageFile` is not `nil`, you are making the assumption that `imageData` passed to the closure is not `nil`. I would check that the image actually exists at server side, and modify your closure code as follows:

```
if let imageData = imageData {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        var contentImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
        self.feedView.image = contentImage
    }
} else {
    // Something happened
}
```

Remember that an explicitly unwrapped optional can technically be `nil` - it's still an optional, but you are instructing the compiler to consider it as a non optional (i.e. automatically unwrap).

Also note that you are modifying a UI component from a thread that is probably not the main. It's better to enclose it in a `dispatch_async` on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried your code, but I still get the same "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error.

Comment: can you step through the code and figure out which line is raising the exception?

Comment: When I attempt to step into the code, it takes me to the viewController with the above code in it, but it does not highlight any particular line....Perhaps I'm doing it wrong? I've also edited my question to include the screen shot of the error i'm receiving.

Comment: Did you try setting breakpoints? good places are the `if` statement, and the first line in the closure

Comment: Yes, the first time the error occurs is on the if let imageData = imageData line...All breaks set before that point work

Comment: Any thoughts? Or perhaps somewhere or someone else you can point me?

Comment: I ended up deleting everything and re-writing it pretty much the exact same way....and it worked....no idea why or how. But your post is correct, and makes my code a little safer as well, so thank you very much!

Comment: Great - it probably was one of those small irrelevant bugs that get unnoticed. Suggestion: do not add content to answers because other devs reading the answers may think it's mine - it's confusing. Rather, add a section to your question when you have to address something to a specific person or answer

Comment: My apologies. I didn't mean to add it to yours, let me try to take it down.

Comment: np - so it was just a mistake :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62861/discussion-between-user3353890-and-antonio).