# Swift Error - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: parsing, swift, xcode6

My app is crashing when it gets to this block.

```
let uploadFile:PFFile = tweet["uploadedPic"] as PFFile
uploadFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (uploadData:NSData!, error:NSError!)-> Void in
     let uploadImage:UIImage = UIImage(data: uploadData)!
     cell.attachedImage.image = uploadImage
}
```

Why would I be receiving this error?

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This questions pops up at least 5 times a day on SO.

Comment: Attempted to improve your question (it's a ***low quality question***) but couldn't, so I've flagged as VLQ. Please add more details such as the code before the crash happens.

Comment: @cybermonkey what do you mean? I have narrowed it down to this block of code everything else is fine :)

Comment: In which line you got this error?

Comment: @user3679109 You obviously haven't done any research, as well as this you haven't explained ***what your app does*** and *what the code **does** that you have included*.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni the crash shows on the first line but I don't think that is it

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint or added println() statements to isolate your problem? Have you checked if `uploadData` is nil? Have you checked if `error` is set? Have you checked if `UIImage(data: uploadData)` (without the exclamation mark!) returns nil?

Comment: @cybermonkey it is a social network and this block is finding the image that the user uploaded to the server and applying it to a UIImageView

Comment: If you try doing [a Google search](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=unexpectedly+found+nil+while+unwrapping+an+Optional+value), you'll see that the first 5 results are your question. The first 3 of those links are on Stack Overflow. If none of those answers solve your problem, try explaining how your problem is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
if let uploadImage = UIImage(data: uploadData)!{
 cell.attachedImage.image = uploadImage
}
```

This error occurs because your `uploadData` is become nil at run time so check your code and find out yourself that why `uploadData` is become nil at run time.

This code will not give you any error if your `uploadData` will be nil.

**EDIT:**

If you get this error on first line then you can do like this way :

```
if let uploadFile = tweet["uploadedPic"] as? PFFile {
// Your code
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had an error in the if statement where you had the ! and I changed it to ? and the error was gone. The app crash is still occurring and showing on the same line. Anything else it could be?

Comment: Thank you very much! It is fixed now, have approved the answer :)

Comment: happy to help you.. and you can refer this question to make your code more explicit.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948401/unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-when-retriveing-pffi